# Retrieve inline image data

Tags: python, screen-scraping, inline

I know this topic has been covered, but after looking through a lot of replies I still don't have anything working

I am trying to retrieve the inline/embedded image data in an shtml file that has been stored locally [a weather data map]. I am using the procudure here:

```
import base64

MyPageData='IDQ21035.shtml'
# or http://www.bom.gov.au/products/IDQ21035.shtml for live data


encoded_str = MyPageData.split('base64,')[-1]

with open('my_file.png', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(base64.b64decode(encoded_str))
```

But get a zero length png file, after an error about incorrect padding.

The date file itself is about 100k, the image is quite large and there are also several smaller images as decorators for the page.

I am sure I've seen somewhere a procedure to do exactly this task, that is, retrieve an image file from being embedded in markup code.

I have looked hard at the previous answers- pls don't just disregard. Also, I'm not tied to Python though it's what the rest of the project uses. I'd thought of dd, if the image data has what could be used as a RS. But this must be such a commonly needed operation.

tia

[file with inline png](http://www.bom.gov.au/products/IDQ21035.shtml)

Comment: afaik you can get always correct padding by appending 3 ='s  `base64.b64decode(encoded_str +"===")`  but that may be urlsafe base64 which has some different padding and some characters (its hard to say without actually seeing the base64)

Comment: I'd seen that, the last few characters in the png block are ErkJggg==">

Comment: Have also added a link to the original file in the original post, I can't figure out how to attach a local zip file of that page though